# I can not retrieve video or can not fetch video from mongodb to my UI frontend

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I can not retrieve video or can not fetch video from mongodb  to my UI frontend  where i stored videos in a array. please give any suggestion.i tried my best

i only getting its file path when using get method

Need your help guys!

```
                    {videolist.map(video => {

                
                       console.log(video.videos)
                      return(

                        
                     <video controls>
                     <source src="/files\1669374105146_s (2).mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                      
                    
                     </video>

                     )
                    })}
```

Comment: So, do you see any errors? You can get the links but you are not able to render the videos?  What is the issue here?

Comment: yes mate. i can get links status also 200.but video cant load and play.is there any way render videos in my ui ? i am  using mongo db.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `load()` function in your `useEffect` to load the video any time the video source changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector("video").load();
}, [])
```

Also, `src` links should have a forward slash. I see you have a back slash in your link. `/files\1669374105146_s (2).mp4` possibly should be `/files/1669374105146_s (2).mp4`

Comment: videosource what i should do ?

Comment: Just remove it and pass empty array []

Comment: i tried but it does not work. we have to store video in any middleware or somrthing i dont know and then render it. your code will work if we have video in local file in client folder.